# prevent default of click event when keyup event ocuurs in angular2

Tags: html, css, angular2-forms

In search input field when keyup event is fired, data showing, after keyup event is fire again click event is working, but I want once keyup or click is fired other one will not work.

Here is my form in **header.html**

```
<form>
     <div class="box">
         <div class="container-1">
            <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Type 
                 your search..." name="searchStr" (keyup.enter)="searchKey(input.value)" 
                [(ngModel)]="searchStr" #input>
            <a (click)="searchKey(input.value)"><img 
              src="/assets/search.png" class="search-img"></a>
        </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

Here is my **header.component.ts**

```
searchKey(value: any) {
    console.log(value);
    this.router.navigate(['search', { searchkey : value }]);
}
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a flag variable which will checks whether to search or not like,

```
export ... {

    flag = true;

    searchKey(value: any) {
        console.log(value);
        this.flag && this.router.navigate(['search', { searchkey : value }]);
        this.flag=false;
    }

    // don't forget to add a condition when flag must be set to true.
}
```

Hope this will help you.